# Error - When I compile or click to create a project

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, build.gradle

**That Error Msg.**
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project /Volumes/Macintosh Database/iFolder Save/Application/Android/Developer/

> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:clean
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>   Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
>   Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest
>   Task :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   Task :app:compileDebugShaders
>   Task :app:generateDebugAssets
>   Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources
>   Task :app:processDebugResources
>   Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
>   Task :app:compileDebugSources
>   Task :app:dexBuilderDebug
>   Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource FAILED
>   Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug
>   Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
>   Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   com.google.common.base.VerifyException (no error message)
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
21 actionable tasks: 20 executed, 1 up-to-date

**//--- I tried all of the suggestions in this text and didn't go away. Try creating a new project and compiling the same message as well. ---//**